# RxJava filtering with inside object

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

For start I must say I am begginer in RxJava.

Data class:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "google_book")
    data class GoogleBook (
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int=0,
        val items: ArrayList<VolumeInfo>)
    
    data class VolumeInfo(val volumeInfo: BookInfo){
        data class BookInfo(val title: String, val publisher: String, val description: String, val imageLinks: ImageLinks?)
        data class ImageLinks(val smallThumbnail: String?)
    }
```

Function which helps me save data to database:

```
        fun searchBooks(query: String) {
            searchJob?.cancel()
            searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
                val text = query.trim()
                if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    bookRepository.getBooksFromApi(query)
                        .map { t ->
                            t.items.map {
                                it.volumeInfo.imageLinks?.smallThumbnail?.filter { x -> x != null }
                            }
                            t
                        }
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe { x ->
                            x?.let { googleBook ->
                                searchJob?.cancel()
                                searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
                                    bookRepository.deleteGoogleBook()
                                    bookRepository.insertGoogleBook(googleBook)
                                }
                            } ?: kotlin.run {
                                Log.d(TAG, "observeTasks: Error")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

As seen I want to filter list within GoogleBook object by image parameter but It doesnt work. I cannot add filtering for data class ImageLinks so I have no Idea how can I make it right

I am asking mostly about this part:

```
                     .map { t ->
                            t.items.map {
                                it.volumeInfo.imageLinks?.smallThumbnail?.filter { x -> x != null }
                            }
                            t
                        }
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

welcome to RxJava, you gonna love it.

As far as I can tell the issue with your filtering simply relies here:

```
.map { t ->
    t.items.map {
        it.volumeInfo.imageLinks?.smallThumbnail?.filter { x -> x != null })
    } // this returns you a new list filtered list here, but does not modify the original one
    t // but you return the same data object here, it is not modified at all
}
// also consider naming it bookInfo if it is actually a bookInfo
```

What you should do is make a copy of your object with the filtered elements, something like this:

```
fun filterGoogleBookBySmallThumbNail(googleBook: GoogleBook): GoogleBook {
    val filteredItems = googleBook.items.filter { it.volumeInfo.imageLinks?.smallThumbnail == null }
    return googleBook.copy(items = ArrayList(filteredItems)) // now a new googleBook item is created with the filtered elements
}

 // snippet to adjust then
 bookRepository.getBooksFromApi(query)
     .map { googleBook -> filterGoogleBookBySmallThumbNail(googleBook) }
     //...
```

*Some additional notes / suggestions I have:*

1. I don't see you actually disposing of the subscription of the Observable.

`bookRepository.getBooksFromApi(query)` If this line returns an Observable, even if you cancel the job, you will be still observing that Observable. If it returns a Single then you are in luck, because after one element it is disposed.
To properly dispose, in cancellation you would have to do something like this(still i would recommend the other two rather, just wanted to note the not disposing):

```
searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
    val text = query.trim()
    if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
        val disposable = bookRepository.getBooksFromApi(query)
            //...
            .subscribe { x ->
            //...
            }
        try {
            awaitCancellation() // this actually suspends the coroutine until it is cancelled
        } catch (cancellableException: CancellationException) {
            disposable.dispose() // this disposes the observable subscription
// that way the coroutine stays alive as long as it's not cancelled, and at that point it actually cleans up the Rx Subscription
        }
```

2. Seems wasteful that you start a new coroutine job just to do actions

If you want to go the Rx way, you could make the
`bookRepository.deleteGoogleBook()` and `bookRepository.insertGoogleBook(googleBook)` Completable, and setup the observable as:

```
bookRepository.getBooksFromApi(query)
//..
.flatMap {
    bookRepository.deleteGoogleBook().andThen(bookRepository.insertGoogleBook(it)).andThen(Observable.just(it))
}
//..subscribeOn
.subscribe()
```

3. Seems weird you are mixing coroutine and RX this way

if you don't want to go full Rx, you may consider converting your Observable into a kotlin coroutine Flow, that would be easier to handle with coroutine cancellations and calling suspend functions.

I hope it's helpful

Comment: Thanks for long answer ;D. I have two weeks to learn RxJava for First job so I am very thankfull

Comment: Unfortunatly Your answer doesnt work. 
I cannot change those name of variable becouse of json .
I try to catch when imageLinks data class doesnt exists or image link doesnt exist. 
When I tried your awnswer with little fix related to data class, I got error that I didnt handle onError in subscribe which isnt true

Comment: I probably missed some brackets maybe. Or something with the data class, let me edit.

Comment: The filter you wrote by itself doesn't really makes sense to me, you seem to filter characters? Maybe I am missing something "it.volumeInfo.imageLinks?.smallThumbnail?.filter { x -> x != null }"

Edited the answer based on your answer about imageLinks existing or not